# how to get the output from windows form to a class?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i want to get output from windows form to the calling application that is class library.

```
Form1 f=new Form1();
f.Show();
if(f.PropertyName!=null)
{
}
```

f.PropertyName is always null. After f.show() it straightaway runs if ()condition. is there any way to get the output from the form1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Show()` is non-blocking. Use `ShowDialog()`, or add a delegate to the `FormClosing()` event of your form and move your `if()` logic into it.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of a lambda "delegate" for the closing event:

```
f.FormClosing += (sender, e) => { /* your code here */ };
```

**EDIT 2:** Whether you handle `FormClosed()` or `FormClosing()` depends on your specific needs. If you want to cancel the form close on a "bad" value, `FormClosing()` lets you cancel the form close.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use ShowDialog() instead of Show().

Answer (score 1):

```
Form1 f=new Form1();
if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  if(f.PropertyName!=null)
  {
  }
}
```